# Google Apps Scripts: Is there a Key-Value List Datatype?

Tags: javascript, google-apps-script

i wanted to use Google Apps Scripts to analyze a Google Sheet.
I want to analyze how common certain answers are and wanted to use a map or dictionary to implement this.

My problem is, no suitable datatype seems to work inside Google Apps Script. I also read the tipp to just use objects with a key value, but it doesnt seem like Google Apps Scripts support the values parameter, generally associated with javascript objects.

So are there any types of key-value datastructure, that i can use and that has working functions for giving out the keys or values ?

Comment: Question is very unclear. Show your coding attempt and exactly what isn't working, because what you ask is a basic standard JavaScript feature (which does work in Apps Script)

Comment: First i created an object `x` and populated it using `x["key1"] = 3; x["key2"] = 1; ...` this still worked. Then i tried to get all the key values i have added before by calling `var t = Objects.keys(x)` and also `var t = x.keys` both ways didnt get recognized by the google script engine. Please check again if you are sure that this really works in Apps Script, because for me it doesnt.

Comment: objects do work in apps script. try for (i in x)

Answer (score 2):

Are you looking for a datastructure to store and retrieve map type data or is it just for processing?

The PropertiesServices and the CacheServices are the closest to what you are looking for. However, they take only strings as keys and values so you can build a mechanism on top of it to support objects in addition to string values.

You can use this helpful library that was created by github user yinonavraham that supports putting/getting objects in Cache 
https://github.com/yinonavraham/GoogleAppsScripts/tree/master/EnhancedCacheService

While yinonavraham has built it for the CacheService,  you can easily build an equivalent for the PropertiesService following his lead.